# Google maps inside fragment of drawer, No view found for id XXXXXXX

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

> ERROR: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: groep2.project4, PID: 18507
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00a5
>   (groep2.project4:id/map) for fragment SupportMapFragment{b36c267 #0
>   id=0x7f0d00a5}

DrawerActivity.java

```
} else if (id == R.id.locatie) { fragment = fragLocatie;
    if(!sMapFragment.isAdded()) {
        sFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, sMapFragment).commit();
    }else{sFragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(sMapFragment).commit();}
```

Locatie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

content_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_start"
    tools:context="groep2.project4.DrawerActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_drawer"
    android:background="#7EC580"
    android:orientation="vertical">




    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="23">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Correct me if im wrong but i think its because the map isnt a child of the drawer activity, but i ony want to display the map in the "locatie" fragment.

can anyone guide me in the right direction here? moving the maps to the content_drawer.xml makes it visible in all fragments, and i have absolutely no clue how to fix this

edit:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        sMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
//        navigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.DKGRAY));

        menucolormanager.HeadingCharts(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.categorie1),navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.categorie2),navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.categorie3), navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.categorie4));

        sMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();


        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment;

        if(sMapFragment.isAdded()){
            sFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(sMapFragment).commit();
        }

        if (id == R.id.fietstrommels) {fragment = fragFietsTrommels;

        } else if (id == R.id.diefstallen) { fragment = fragDiefstallen;

        } else if (id == R.id.locatie) { fragment = fragLocatie;
            if(!sMapFragment.isAdded()) {
                sFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, sMapFragment).commit();
            }else{sFragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(sMapFragment).commit();}

        } else if (id == R.id.route) { fragment = fragRoute;

        } else if (id == R.id.kladblok) { fragment = fragKladblok;

        } else {return false;}

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer_start, fragment).commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: can you post the code where you are initializing and adding `SupportMapFragment` ??

Comment: add your java code as well

Comment: Added the OnNavigationItemSelected and OnCreate methods

Comment: The ID you pass to a `FragmentTransaction` needs to be for a `ViewGroup` that is in the current layout, that will hold the `Fragment`. Is the `FrameLayout` with ID `map` in the `Activity`'s layout?

Comment: `Locatie.xml` is layout for `Locatie` fragment right?? I just want to know if you are loading `SupportMapFragment` inside `fragment` or `activity`??

Comment: Yes, Locatie.xml is for the Locatie fragment. @himanshu1496

Comment: @MikeM. I have no idea, im doing this for a school project and its the first time im playing with android. what i did was change the map xml code to the content_Drawer because thats the child of the activity but that messes things up even more.

Comment: Also, when i move the layout part with the id:maps in it to the content_drawer it works, but then on all the other fragments it doesnt show the fragment contents anymore

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Locatie fragment` class while adding `SupportMapFragment` you have to use `ChildFragmentManager` as fragmentManager because you are adding fragment inside a fragment. Below is the sample code:

```
FragmentManager sFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
sFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, sMapFragment).commit()
```

Hope it works, let me know if you have trouble implementing the same.

Comment: It does kinda work, but im having trouble using mapsyncing now seeing that 
        sMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
is not possible inside the fragment

Comment: It is possible, your fragment class must implements `OnMapReadyCallback` and it works like charm.

Comment: public class Locatie extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

it does, but getMapAsync() is not callable from a fragment(only activity)

Comment: no you have to call it from `supportMapFragment` i.e. `sMapFragment.getMapAsync(this)` after doing fragmentTransaction commit.